# NoClassDefFoundError for MapperBuilder

Tags: java, jmeter, libraries

I'm developing plugins for JMeter and, as part of the process, we added some third party libraries.

When I run the app, I got an error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder
    at io.lindstrom.mpd.MPDParser.defaultObjectMapper(MPDParser.java:57) ~[mpd-parser-0.6.jar:?]
    at io.lindstrom.mpd.MPDParser.<init>(MPDParser.java:33) ~[mpd-parser-0.6.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.hls.logic.HlsSampler.sample(HlsSampler.java:237) ~[jmeter-bzm-hls-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    ... 9 more
```

I have been adding libraries as the ClassNotFoundException has been "requesting" but, this one, I cant find to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing classes are from [jackson-databind](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) jar

You should put dependant jars for plugin in [lib folder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) (although plugin jar itself is in lib/ext folder)

> JMeter automatically finds classes from jars in the following directories:
>
> JMETER_HOME/lib
>   used for utility jars
>   JMETER_HOME/lib/ext
>   used for JMeter components and plugins
>
> If you have developed new JMeter components, then you should jar them and copy the jar into JMeter's lib/ext directory. JMeter will automatically find JMeter components in any jars found here. **Do not use lib/ext for utility jars or dependency jars used by the plugins**

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Jackson databind pre release was giving me hell. Now It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Dependent jar is not present, which is causing class not found exception. Add jackson-databind `https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind` jar  to jmeter external lib `JMETER_HOME/lib/ext/`  folder.